# Angular Material Dialog action buttons appear on the top (and not on the bottom)

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

[image: Here's what I see]

relevant code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"
```

And,

```
$mdDialog.show(
              $mdDialog.alert()
                .clickOutsideToClose(true)
                .title('Please Login')
                .textContent('Please use facebook to login to Afsheen before making a purchase.')
                .ok('Got it!')
                .targetEvent(event)
            );
```

Any idea whats going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using both bootstrap and material css together, which is causing the issue, Check the material versions are same,

Here is the working [`App`](https://plnkr.co/edit/jDuB5F?p=preview)

Comment: we can use both of them together, issue is I was using an older angular material css.